# Fields autofill ( like name, email, picture ) with google account on SignUp

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I implemented google sign in on my app, but i want people to sign up with google, auto filling fields like name, email and maybe password. How can i do that? I've tried to use text in TextEditingController but it's not working.